# Filtering IEnumerable child property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, automapper

I'm attempting to bring back a list of objects. This object has an IEnumerable property of a second class. I'm attempting to filter this child list based on a condition.

There are the classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int OtherId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the EF code where I am attempting to get the parents and filter the children:

```
public IEnumerable<ParentViewModel> GetParents(int otherId)
{
    var parents = _databaseContext.Parents
        .Include(i => i.Children.Where(child => child.OtherId == otherId));

    return parents;
}
```

When I call this method, I get an ArgumentException, with the message:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type.
Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for 
collection navigation properties.
```

Given that the exception mentions using Select, I've tried doing that too:

```
public IEnumerable<ParentViewModel> GetParents(int otherId)
{
    var parents = _databaseContext.Parents
        .Where(parent => parent.Active == true)
        .Include(parent => parent.Children);
        .Select(parent => new 
        {
            Active = parent.Active,
            Id = parent.Id,
            Children = parent.Children
                .Where(child => child.OtherId == propertyId)
                .Select(child => new
                {
                    Active = child.Active,
                    Id = child.Id,
                    ParentId = child.ParentId,
                    OtherId = child.OtherId,
                    Title = child.Title
                },
            Title = parent.Title
        });
    return parents;
}
```

This also blows up, giving me the exception:

```
The specified type member 'Children' is not supported in LINQ to 
Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
properties are supported.
```

And that's where I'm all out of ideas! I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but this doesn't feel like it should be as hard as it has been, so I'm guessing that I'm missing something pretty fundamental to Entity Framework.

Comment: For me it looks like that your Child Class is not in your Entity Model. So EF can't translate it to valid Sql.
So I see two Options:
Add the Child Table to the Model and your Queries should work OR
Call .ToList() on your Parents and then you can Query with Linq2Objects.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the Parent and Child classes at the top are my entities, so the Child is on the Parent as an IEnumerable. Unless you mean something else which I'm not getting?

Comment: Do you use EF Code First oder did you generate the Model from an existing Database?

Comment: I use Code First to interact with the database, but it is an existing database rather than one created with Code First.

Comment: It's probably just a typo, but in your code snippet you're not creating new `ParentViewModel`s. Could you find out which of the two `parent.Children` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok! I am not familiar with Code First (I am using a generated model in my Project) but I am pretty sure that EF doesn't recognize that these Entities are related. The error Message: " ... and entity navigation properties are supported" tells me that you should define a navigation property (a Relation between these Entities).

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int OtherId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int ParentId [get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do have a context set up manually. I've changed it to ICollection, but that hasn't made any difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer and changed your classes by adding Data Annotations and a Property. If this doensn't work, can you please post the design of the Database Tables?

Comment: It didn't work. I've worked around it for now (ran out of time to investigate this), but I will come back to it, as I am determined to get this to work!